# Why do I keep getting a 404 error when trying to load the Pic of the day from nasa?

Tags: javascript, html

Im working with Nasa's Astronomy Picture of The Day and I've managed to pull the description of the picture, the title of the picture, and who is credited with taking the picture.  The only thing I am missing is the center piece itself, the actual picture from Nasa.  I have been able to get ither images to load just fine, but this project is mainly pictures and none of them seem to want to work for me.  When looking at my console I keep getting a 404 error that reads
"GET [https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2004/WindmillStarTrails1024.jpgstyle='width:100%'/](https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2004/WindmillStarTrails1024.jpgstyle=%27width:100%%27/) 400 (Bad Request)"

I believe its an error getting the url of the picture but I am not sure how to fix it.  I have been successful in getting other pictures to work out and have formatted this one in the exact same way, so I am not sure what makes this picture different from the others if it is.  Below is the HTML with the script that I used.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> NASA API Demo </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div id="output">
    <thing id="img"></thing>
    <p id = "copyright"> </p>
    <h1 id = "title"></h1>
    <p id="explanation"> </p>
</div>
<script>
        fetch('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=(My Key Here)
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((endUpWith) => {
        document.getElementById("img").innerHTML="<img src=" +endUpWith.url+ "style='width:100%'/>";

        document.getElementById("copyright").innerHTML="By " + endUpWith.copyright;
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML=endUpWith.title;
        document.getElementById("explanation").innerHTML=endUpWith.explanation;

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspect the element you added to the page. It is going to look like

```
<img src=https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2004/WindmillStarTrails1024.jpgstyle='width:100%' />
```

Because you are not using quotes and the url is hooked up to the style attribute. Add quotes around the source, add a space.

```
"<img src='" +endUpWith.url + "' style='width:100%'/>"
          ^                    ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

I would invert from double quotes to single ones, at least for this line:

```
document.getElementById("img").innerHTML='<img src="' +endUpWith.url+ '" style="width:100%"/>';
```

Easier to read. Actually, I would recommend to treat JS strings with single quotes.